# I got the from date and to date from the user. I want to return the Sold Product's price and its count in the basis of Daily sold order. how?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, group-by, django-queryset

```
models.Order.objects.filter(purchasedate__range=[from_date, to_date])

today_total = 0
            quant = 0
            for values in daterangeorder:
                today_total += values.price
                quant += values.quantity

return response.Response({
            "from_date": from_date,
            "to_date": to_date,
            "Amount Sold": str(today_total),
            "Count": str(quant)
        })
```

This is the output:

```
   {
    "from_date": "2021-11-19",
    "to_date": "2021-11-23",
    "Amount Sold": "27000",
    "Count": "9"
}
```

I want like this (day by day sold products count):-

```
{
    date: “'2021-10-20”,
    count: 20,
    total_price_sold: 5000.00
},
{
    date: “'2021-10-21”,
    count: 4,
    total_price_sold: 300.00
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of solving your problem with Python code, you can let the database handle it for you using aggregation, see the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#values

```
from django.db.models import Sum

result = models.Order.objects.values('purchasedate')
    .order_by('purchasedate')
    .annotate(total_price_sold=Sum('price'), count=Sum('quantity'))
return response.Response(result)
```